# Databricks-GitHub integration, automatically add all notebooks to repository

Tags: git, github, automation, databricks

I'm trying to set up **GitHub integration for Databricks**.
We have hundreds of notebooks there, and it would be exhausting to add every notebook manually to the repo.

Is there some way to **automatically commit and push** all notebooks from databricks to repository?

Comment: Could support help you in the end or is this still unresolved?

Comment: As a workaround, they recommended to use Databricks CLI. It allows to download all notebooks and folders. Thus, I can commit and push them all at once.

https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dev-tools/databricks-cli.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since no one answered it for 3 month, I'll put my own solution.

Under `/Shared/` dir in databricks we have notebooks which should be synced to repository under `notebooks/Shared/`.
I run this script on regular basis, thus keeping all notebooks up-to-date in a repo.

```
databricks workspace export_dir /Shared ./notebooks/Shared -o
git add --all
git commit -m "shared notebooks updated"
git push
```

`-o` flag is for overriding existing notebooks with latest version.

More information here:
https://databricks.com/blog/2017/11/08/introducing-command-line-interface-for-databricks-developers.html

Note, you first have to set up and configure databricks-cli on your machine: 
https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dev-tools/databricks-cli.html#set-up-the-cli

Comment: knew about dbfs but didnt know about the workspace option in cli, thanks!!

Comment: ahhhg this is so great. i set up an azure devops build pipeline with it too:
https://gist.github.com/madmaxlax/792cdfba5e31760a351804ed7c36b657

Comment: This is great. Does this automatically link all the notebooks.